# php function outside table cell

Tags: php, html, function

I have made a table and want to add sometext throug a function on a table cell.
The problem is if i use a function it gets displayed outside the table but when i use a variable from the same page it gets displayed inside the table

example:

```
if($t==1)
{
    echo "<table class='overzicht-table' style='float:left;'>";
}
$tekst=check_resultaat($v,$ex_id,$user_id);
echo "<tr><td>$v</td><td>$tekst</td></tr>";

if($t==10)
{
    echo "</table>";
    $t=0;
}

function check_resultaat($vr_nr,$ex_id,$user_id){
$sql="SELECT * FROM app_ex_vr_res WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND ex_id='$ex_id' AND vraagnr='$vr_nr' AND NOT antwoord=''";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

if($result->num_rows === 0)
{
    echo "not answerd";
}
else
{
    echo "answerd";
}
}
```

This breaks and the code gets outside the  field.

But when i change this $tekst=check_resultaat($v,$ex_id,$user_id); into this $tekst="answerd"; it works.

I tried a lot of things but not working for me. This is not the whole code but if you guys need more i can edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `return` statement instead of `echo` inside of that function. Check out PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: thanks that did the job. it did work in other places.